# Como checar o id de um item em uma classe no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Basicamente eu tenho uma classe, e cada item dessa classe tem um `id`, como eu faço pra checar se esse `id` é igual a um valor específico? e, se detectar tal valor, como alterar para uma imagem diferente?

Meu código ta assim:

```html
<img class="figuras id="quad" src="quadrado.jpg" onclick="trocaFigura()" alt = "quadrado" style = "width: 200px;">
<img class="figuras id="pen" src="pentagono.jpg" onclick="trocaFigura()" alt = "pentagono" style = "width: 200px;">
<img class="figuras id="tri" src="triangulo.jpg" onclick="trocaFigura()" alt = "triangulo" style = "width: 200px;">
<img class="figuras id="exa" src="exagono.jpg"   onclick="trocaFigura()" alt = "exagono" style = "width: 200px;">

<script>
function trocaFigura(){
    var form = document.getElementsByClassName("figuras");
    if()
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
<img class="figuras id="quad" src="quadrado.jpg" onclick="trocaFigura(0)" alt = "quadrado" style = "width: 200px;">

<script>
  trocaFigura(indice){
    document.getElementsByClassName('nome_da_classe')[indice].id
  }
</script>
```

Basicamente, faltou pegar o índice, já que é um array. Você pode fazer um foreach e checar se o elemento atual bate com o valor que você quer testar.

Outra opção que pode funcionar:

```
document.querySelector('.nome_da_classe').id
```

Observações: `getElementsByClassName` Não é suportado pelo IE 6-8 e `querySelector` não é suportado pelo IE6-7 & FF3

Comment: Isso não funciona para o item que foi clicado. Isso só "selecionará" o primeiro elemento de classe `nome_da_classe`. Note que a pergunta é embasada num contexto de evento `click`.

Comment: Realmente, complementei a resposta, obrigado Luiz

Answer (score 1):

Antes de responder sua pergunta, deixe-me fazer algumas observações sobre ela e sobre o seu código:

- não sei se foi erro de digitação mas, não está fechando as aspas no atributo `class`, deveria ser `class="figuras"`;
- note que todos os elementos tem o mesmo estilo, pode então passar o `width: 200px` para o css e remover do elemento;
- *"cada item dessa classe tem um id, como eu faço pra checar se esse id é igual a um valor específico"*, como todos elementos chamam a mesma *function*, basta passar o elemento para dentro da *function* e já vai ter o ID :). Assim: `onclick="trocaFigura(this)"`. Neste caso o `this` representa o próprio elemento que está disparando o evento, ou seja, o elemento que foi clicado. Note que, assim nem é preciso a class, porque no seu código ela estava sendo usada para encontrar as imagens, mas mantive aproveitando para fazer o que uma class deve fazer, ter estilos, e coloquei nela o `width`.

Veja abaixo algumas mudanças baseadas nos comentários acima:

```js
// estou procurando pelo id "tri"
var idDesejado = "tri";

function trocaFigura(img) {
   // img é a variável que aponta para a imagem que disparou o evento, onde foi clicado, então "img.id" retorna o ID
   console.log(img.id);
   if (img.id == idDesejado) {
      console.log("mudando a imagem");
      // aqui, mudo o src, ou seja, a imagem
      img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRKnY.png";
   }
}
```

```css
.figuras {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="figuras" id="quad" src="quadrado.jpg" onclick="trocaFigura(this)" alt="quadrado" />
<img class="figuras" id="pen" src="pentagono.jpg" onclick="trocaFigura(this)" alt="pentagono"/>
<img class="figuras" id="tri" src="triangulo.jpg" onclick="trocaFigura(this)" alt="triangulo"/>
<img class="figuras" id="exa" src="exagono.jpg"   onclick="trocaFigura(this)" alt="exagono"/>
```